# Unable to bind default value to dropdown in knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am having two dropdown (PrimarySpeciality,PrimarySubSpeciality), based on the value in one dropdown(PrimarySpeciality) the other dropdown(PrimarySubSpeciality) value should change.

On Load, I want the 'PrimarySubSpecialities' on load to default value.

How can i do it?

my cshtml:

```
 <div class="nmc-righttab" style="width:265px;">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User.PSpecialty, Model.PSpecialties, new { id = "ddUserDetails", style = "width:245px;height:25px;",  data_bind = "event: {change: primaryChanged}" }, Model.IsReadOnly)
      </div>
 <div  style="width:265px;">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User.PSubSpecialty,Model.PSubspecialties, new { id = "ddUserDetailsPSubSpeciality", style = "width:245px;height:25px;",  data_bind = "options: pSubSpecialities,optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: 'Id',value:PSubspecialty,enable:isPSpecialitySelected" })
   </div>
```

My JS File:

```
    this.PSubspecialty = ko.observable($('#ddUserDetails').val());
    this.pSubSpecialities = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.isPSpecialitySelected = ko.observable(false);

    this.pSpecilaityChanged = function () {

        var pSpecialityVal = $("#ddUserDetails").val();
        if (pSpecialityVal) {
            model.isPSpecialitySelected(true);
            pStartIndex = 0;
            pSubSpecialityUrl = '/User/GetSpec?pSpeciality=' + pSpecialityVal +'&sSpeciality=';
            loadPSubSpecilaities();
        }
        else
        {
            model.isSelected(false);
        }
    };
```

On Load,I want to set initial value for 'pSubSpeciality' to be text as '<>' with value as '0'.

Even I am able to add  item to Model.PSubSpecialties,but could not be able to display the added item in psubspeciality dropdown.

How can set the  initial value to pSubSpecialityDropdown from Model.PSubSpecialities.

Answer (score 0):

Work within your model more, and with the UI less. Instead of making a `changed` event on the DropDownList items, `subscribe` to changes on a `value`-bound variable. In your PrimarySpecialty DropDown,

```
data_bind = "value: primarySpecialty"
```

Then in your JS:

```
var self = this;    
this.primarySpecialty = ko.observable();
this.isPrimarySpecialtySelected = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return !!self.primarySpecialty();
});
this.primarySubSpeciality = ko.observable();
//...
this.primarySpecialty.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        loadPrimarySubSpecialities();
        this.primarySubSpeciality('0'); // Set default, by value
    }
});
```

If the PrimarySubSpeciality dropdown has an option whose `Id` member is '0', the item will be selected in it.